# When does user.user_id() change on App Engine app using OpenID authentication?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I have an application using vanilla OpenID support from GAE platform. I use [`user_id()`](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_user_id) as an common — as I understand immutable — id for everything concerning users.

But from time to time I notice that user_id changes for some users. What causes the change in user_id for a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't ever change. What circumstances do you see it change in? How do you determine it's the same user?

On the other hand, the Google OpenID provider acts in a way that is domain-dependent: when a user signs in with their Google account, it generates a new, custom OpenID URL that depends on the domain they're signing in to. If your app exists on multiple domains, and authenticates users on each, you'll get a different OpenID URL (and hence user_id) for the same user on each domain.

This is a consequence of how the Google OpenID provider works, unfortunately, and there's not really any way around it, other than either only serving on one domain, or asking your users to combine their OpenID URLs.

Comment: I haven't diagnose that reason yet — ergo my question. I though maybe it's connected to the fact that my app is accesible through few domains (dziennik.pspo.edu.pl, www.dl.edu.pl or www.DziennikLekcyjny.edu.pl).

Comment: Every time user authenticates with OpenID we fetch a profile for corresponding user_id, or look for pre-created user profile with matching email (then activation message is send). If profile for current user_id is not found, but there is one with matching email, then we check if it's already activated (has user_id set) and compare user_id's to prevent account hijacking. Sometimes user_id changes, and as far as I know these are not connected with OpenID identity change.

Comment: One other thing, some users are authenticating with Google Apps for Education accounts. Some have had account's activated — and user_id stored — before their Google Apps accounts where converted to the new type allowing their usage as Google Accounts. I have blamed this change for user_id change, but it did not result in all user_id changes, and changes where observed for vanilla Google Account users.

Comment: Ah. Yes, it is related to your domains. I'll update the answer to explain.

Comment: I think that many domains are not a solo reason. I have been accesing my app through different domains and I never had a problem with chainging user_id…

Comment: @WooYek Are you using OpenID? It's definitely the case that the Google OpenID provider issues different URLs for the same user on different domains.

Comment: @Nick, this would mean that for every `VERSION.latest.myapp.appspot.com` I should get different `user_id` and I get the same one. Or I did not understand it correctly :/

Comment: @WooYek It should, yes, unless the Google OpenID provider is special-casing that. I'm not sure if it does or not.